# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText on a null object reference

Tags: android, json

я пытаюсь сделать так,чтобы при нажатии кнопки на первом Activity,открывался второй и разбирал .json файл,но появляется ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.maxim.myapplicationtest, PID: 9024
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.maxim.myapplicationtest.data.onPostExecute(data.java:64)
                  at com.example.maxim.myapplicationtest.data.onPostExecute(data.java:18)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Что только не пробовал делать,все безрезультатно,но если сначала открывать второй Activity,а уже потом кнопкой разбирать .json,то тогда все работает.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button click;
Button btnbutton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    click.setOnClickListener(this);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            com.example.maxim.myapplicationtest.data process = new data();
            process.execute();
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

И Data:

```
public class data extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
String data ="";
String DataParsed ="";
String SingleParsed ="";
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://test.json");

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }

        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for(int i =0 ;i <JA.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            SingleParsed ="Создано:"  + JO.get("date") + "\n"+
                          "Заголовок:"  + JO.get("title") + "\n"+
                          "Текст:"  + JO.get("teaserHTML") + "\n"+
                          "Просмотров:"  + JO.get("viewsCount") + "\n"+
                          "Комментариев:"  + JO.get("commentsCount") + "\n";

            DataParsed = DataParsed + SingleParsed;
        }
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    MainActivity2.data.setText(this.SingleParsed);
}
```

Comment: Активити, которая в данный момент не отображается на экране, условно не существует. Вы не можете обращаться к полям и методам такой активити, во избежании NPE (что по итогу и имеете).

Answer (score 1):

1. Нельзя получить доступ к элементам активности из другой
2. Зачем вам нужно после выполнения `AsynсTask` что-либо менять в другой активности, если ее даже не существует в этот момент. Если эти данные нужны во второй активности передайте их через `Intent`.

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("extra", "yourString"):
startActivity(intent);`

В второй активности считайте:

```
String yourString = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra")
```

Comment: можно получить) если активность в стеке, а переменная статическая. Но это неправильно, да

Comment: @Jarvis_J будем считать, что нельзя, чтобы никто не пытался писать порнографию

Comment: считайте, как считаете нужным)

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно читайте логи. Там даже подчеркнута строчка, где у вас ошибка. Вангую: `MainActivity2.data.setText(this.SingleParsed);`

Вы из активности номер 1 выставляете текст в активности номер 2 (которая еще не создана).

В момент `setText(...)` ваша статическая переменная `MainActivity2.data` еще не инициализирована. Вообще, не рекомендуется использовать статические переменные `TextView`. Инфу можно передавать через `Intent` или `interface`.

Подумайте над другой реализацией или поясните, что вы хотите получить в итоге.